# How do I specify starting location in a ForEach using GeometryReader?

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui

I have a project where I list pieces of art. Once a piece is selected you go into a detail view. From there, I want you to be able to swipe up and down to go to the previous or next piece in the list.

I'm using a filtered ForEach for the list view and a ForEach with GeometryReader for the detail view.

How do I make the detail view start on the correct piece instead of just starting at the beginning of a ForEach?

Thanks for any help!

Code snippets:

**LIST VIEW**

```
          ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                LazyVStack(spacing:0) {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    if user_settings.isSortTitle == true {
                        ForEach(titleSortedArts, id: \.self) { art in
                            NavigationLink(destination:DetailView(art:art)) {
                                ArtRow(art: art)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if user_settings.isSortCreator == true {
                        ForEach(creatorSortedArts, id: \.self) { art in
                            NavigationLink(destination:DetailView(art:art)) {
                                ArtRow(art: art)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        ForEach(arts, id: \.self) { art in
                            NavigationLink(destination:DetailView(art:art)) {
                                ArtRow(art: art)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } // Lazy Vstack
            } // Scrollviewreader
        } // Scrollview
    } // Vstack
```

**DETAIL VIEW**

```
         GeometryReader { geometry in
            return ScrollView(showsIndicators: true) {
                VStack(spacing: self.spacing) {
                    ForEach(arts) { art in
                        DetailHeaderView(art: art)
                        NFTDetail(nft:nft)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    }
                }
            }
            .content.offset(y: self.offset)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .leading)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        self.offset = value.translation.height - geometry.size.height * CGFloat(self.index)
                    })
                    .onEnded({ value in
                        if -value.predictedEndTranslation.height > geometry.size.height / 2, self.index < arts.count {
                            self.index += 1
                        }
                        if value.predictedEndTranslation.height > geometry.size.height / 2, self.index > 0 {
                            self.index -= 1
                        }
                        withAnimation { self.offset = -(geometry.size.height + self.spacing) * CGFloat(self.index) }
                    })
                
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too knowledgeable about this subject, but it seems like iterators would be the best option in this situation. Presumably once you make the iterator you could then set that iterator to a value on tap and then go back to it once you exit.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688032-makeiterator